# Error on adding to empty comboBox in Qt

Tags: qt, combobox

I use Qt 5.2.0 (MSVC 2010).

I added to my form in Qt a ComboBox.

Then I want to fill it with numbers:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    ui->tableCombo->addItem(QString::number(i));
}
```

When I add a first element right in the form, it successfully adds numbers. But when I leave it empty, it throws an error:

> ASSERT failure in QVector::operator[]: "index out of range"

Debugger shows that error occured right in this line. And there is no QVector across the line.

After adding qDebug().

```
qDebug() << "readFileToStringList: msg10";
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    qDebug() << "readFileToStringList: msg20  i = " << i;
    ui->tableCombo->addItem(QString::number(i+1));
    qDebug() << "readFileToStringList: msg30";
}
qDebug() << "readFileToStringList: msg40";
```

I get the same result

```
readFileToStringList: msg10 
readFileToStringList: msg20  i =  0 
ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\5.2.0\mingw48_32\include/QtCore/qvector.h, line 369
```

Comment: it seems that the error is raised from somewhere else in your code. It relates to some QVector.

Comment: You should post code sample that reproduce your problem.

Comment: I ran debug. It raises right in this line. There is no QVector across the line.

Comment: @Nejat, maybe ComboBox uses QVector.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem without success. Post a minimal example that reproduces it.

Comment: Thank you for your trying. It like a ghost, I can't reproduce error outside the project.

Comment: @Michael, OK, can you show us all places when you use ui->tableCombo. You can use Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: "it really was somewhere outside this part of code. The error does not occur anymore." So, you didn't even run it in a debugger to see where the assert triggers? And you offer a *bounty* on that? You'll go broke in short order :)

Comment: @Guinness I use it only in this loop. And there:     tableComboPrevIndex = ui->tableCombo->currentIndex(); And both of them are in the function, that reads file and called from slot.

Comment: @Kuba, Yeah, I changed smth and it becomes work. Then I just placed this loop into function that reads file. And it appears again. Bounty is because this thing makes me angry.

Comment: @Michael How do you expect *anyone* to be able to help you if you don't show the entire code of the application, or at least a minimized version that still shows the problem? The answer to your troubles is in [this blog entry](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Read it. Understand it. Follow it.

Comment: @Michael So, at the moment, do you still have this problem, or not? If you have it, run it in the debugger! Have you run it in the debugger yet? Why do you not show a debugger bak trace (stack trace) at the time when the assert fires?

Comment: @KubaOber I thought somebody already had this error. There is no other corresponded with a problem information. I see, that it is not right. And now I want to delete post to stop spending my and your time to this problem. It works with non-empty combo in the form on the begin. But I can't delete it because of bounty. And Qt Debugger doesn't shows backtrace.

Comment: @Michael The Qt Creator debugger interface does indeed show backtraces. You need to open the stack trace window if you don't have it open.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact problem and couldn't figure it out for a couple hours.  I realized ::addItem() was triggering the indexChanged(int) signal, which I had connected to a function that was causing an out-of-range error in a container.

I would say it was possibly the problem here too, but I'm sure the OP has moved on since then.  To me it isn't exactly intuitive that the indexChanged signal would be called on insertion of new items, since it doesn't actually change the currentIndex.

Hopefully if anyone else gets tripped up this will help them!

Answer (score 1):

**`addItem()` doesn't throw that error!** I'm positive it's coming from another instruction in   your code.

Qt documentation has an entire section on [Debugging Techniques](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/debug.html), but if you are afraid of debuggers you can use the ***poor's man debugger***: spread several `qDebug()` messages before and after the instructions you think are responsible for the problem:

```
qDebug() << "methodX: msg10";

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    qDebug() << "methodX: msg20  i = " << i;
    ui->tableCombo->addItem(QString::number(i));
    qDebug() << "methodX: msg30";
}

qDebug() << "methodX: msg40";
```

If the message `methodX: msg30` gets printed to the screen, means that `addItem()` didn't cause the error.

Comment: Right in this string. Added to question.

Comment: ui - is a main class `Ui::FPWorth *ui;`. As I said before, this line is working if I add first item in the form manually.

Comment: Can you make sure `tableCombo` exists before calling `addItem()`?  `if (!ui->tableCombo) qDebug() << "there is no combo!";`

Comment: I added this line. Yes, the combo exists.

Comment: To help you any further, I'm going to need a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not asking a code that is problem free. I'm asking a minimal version of the problematic code that can be compiled and executed. Do you think you can provide that?

Comment: Yes, I understood you. I'll try to do it.